# Virtual keyboard for Angular on mobile devices

Tags: android, angularjs, mobile, web-applications, virtual-keyboard

I am struggeling on a question of my client to use a custom keyboard on my **webapplication** on a **mobile device**. That keyboard should only have all the digits, a dot, a backspace and an enter. Nothing more, nothing less.

I know you can use the different HTML5 input types (tel, number,...) to get a different keyboard of the Mobile Operating System, but these keyboards are different on each Mobile Operating System (Android, IOS, Windows Mobile): http://mobileinputtypes.com/ - Using the type 'tel' on IOS is ok, but on android I get a whole lot of other options that are not necessary. Same goes for 'number'...

I know it is not possible to customize the default keyboard of an Mobile Operating System.

I have found the plugin http://the-darc.github.io/angular-virtual-keyboard/ that at first sight does the job (look at the **Numeric keyboard with customized css** example). The only problem is that on mobile the default keyboard of the Mobile Operating System always pops up.

Is there a way to not show the default Keyboard or are there any other options that you can think of?

Thanks for the help, much appreciated!